# Ant Java task for Java 1.6

Tags: java, maven, ant, task

Our project uses ant tool to build maven project. We are using java 1.6 and 1.8 for different OS related release. The build works fine for java 1.8 and same is failing when using 1.6 because of versions-maven-plugin which maven downloading is latest and compiled in 1.7.

I tried copying org.codehaus.mojo version plugin of 2.4 in local repository but still maven looking to latest 2.7 version. Is there is way to specify version in ant java task
`<java classname="org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher" fork="true" dir="@{basedir}" resultproperty="@{resultproperty}" failonerror="true">`

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the version of versions-maven-plugin in a pluginManagement section, something like:

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
    </plugin>       
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Refer to: [Maven2: How to be sure Maven build is using a specific plugin version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341776/maven2-how-to-be-sure-maven-build-is-using-a-specific-plugin-version)

Here is the Maven documentation:
https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#plugin-management

Comment: pluginManagement comes under maven pom.xml, but I have build.xml in that mentioning the maven goal.[http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/examples/mvn.html](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/examples/mvn.html) **Using the Java Task**

Comment: OK, so how does the ant task know to download 2.7?  Are you setting maven.home  in your build.xml?  In the same document it seems that the default behaviour will be to download if no local maven install is found.   "Using the Java Task
The java task can be used directly without any need for the Maven Ant Tasks. However, this method requires that Maven is already installed on the system. A property called maven.home must be set to point to the local Maven installation.."

Comment: maven is already installed and provided maven.home in build.xml  
   `<java classname="org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher" fork="true" dir="@{basedir}" 
                  resultproperty="@{resultproperty}" failonerror="true">
                <jvmarg value="-Xmx512m" />
                <classpath>
                    <fileset dir="${propfile.MAVEN3_HOME}/boot">
                        <include name="*.jar" />
                    </fileset>
                    <fileset dir="${propfile.MAVEN3_HOME}/lib">
                        <include name="*.jar" />
                    </fileset>`

Comment: `profile.MAVEN_HOME` property value provided in build.properties and it is maven home directory path. I tried to add the dependency as property `<pathelement location="Misc/versions-maven-plugin-2.4.jar"/>
                    <pathelement path="${java.class.path}"/>`. Still no luck with this.

Comment: The example shows:  <sysproperty key="maven.home" value="${maven.home}" />

Comment: I have set that too. Because of limitation in comment I didn't post complete java task `<sysproperty key="classworlds.conf" value="${propfile.MAVEN3_HOME}/bin/m2.conf" />
                <sysproperty key="maven.home" value="${propfile.MAVEN3_HOME}" />
                <arg line="--batch-mode @{options} @{goal}" />`

Comment: Getting the error like `[java] [INFO] --- versions-maven-plugin:2.7:set (default-cli) @ all-applications ---
     [java] [WARNING] Error injecting: org.codehaus.mojo.versions.SetMojo
     [java] java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.codehaus.mojo.versions.SetMojo not present  [java] Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/codehaus/mojo/versions/SetMojo : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)`